# Check constraint when table is created with default value?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am using oracle 11g. i am creating a table which has few columns. One of the column should have some default value. **If no value is passed then DEFAULT must be considered**. Can i do as below?

Column with default value:

```
ATTENDENT CHAR(1 BYTE) DEFAULT 'N'
```

Constraint:

```
CONSTRAINT "CC_ATTENDENT_CHECK" CHECK (attendent is not null and attendent in ('Y','N')) ENABLE
```

Thanks!

Comment: I've answered below but, are you trying to add some other behaviour to the field?, depending of the incoming value?. I'm not sure of what is the purpose of that check constraint if you only need to set a default for a null value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create / alter a table with a default value, like this:

```
Alter table table_test modify (foo varchar(3) NULL default 'bar');
```

... should be enough to set a default value when you insert a null

Comment: Javier, in that case i need not have check constraint rifht? Because for me clients can send NULL also.

Comment: I've corrected the answer. I've put NOT NULL by mistake... sorry for that.
In addition,in oracle 11g, If you add a new column with a default, it will automatically set default value for all existing records.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can,

eg:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
P_Id int NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255) DEFAULT 'Sandnes'
)
```